# How to rename file names using text file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to rename a bunch of files in a folder with new name reference from a text file. Can you please give an example for this.

**My New Names In a Text file:**

```
1BA
1BB
1BC
1BD
1BE
1BF
1C0
1C1
1C2
1C3
```

Like this.

**Updated Code:**

```
import csv
import os

with open('names.txt') as f2:
         filedata = f2.read().split(",")
         os.rename(filedata[0].strip(), filedata[1].strip())
f2.close()
f2 = open ('Lines.txt','w')
f2.write(filedata)
f2.close()
```

Comment: please show some of your attempts.

Comment: Also it would be good if you give an example of the input text file that contains the new names. Can it be whatever? Does it have a specific format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a CSV (comma separated) file for input in the format `oldPath, newPath` and do the following:

```
import csv
import os

with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         oldPath = row[0]
         newPath = row[1]
         os.rename(oldPath, newPath)
```

Alternatively, if you want to move the file to another directory/filesystem you can have a look at [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

Comment: @lotus Where do you take the old name from? The file seems to have the new name only? You can use `os.rename` again in a loop like: `with open("names.txt") as f: for line in f: ...`. This is reading the file line by line

Comment: yup, somehow you need to the old name. If you go with `oldname, newname` you will need `parts = line.split(",")` to separate old and new names and `os.rename(parts[0].strip(), parts[1].strip())`. The `strip` method will remove any whitespace characters around the name (like trailing ` ` ).

Comment: Can you please give an example text file.I have update my code above.

Comment: Is there is any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create old.txt and rename.txt
# Do not include file path inside the txt files
# For each line, write a filename include the extension

from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

print("enter path of folder")
path = input()

oldList = []
with open(path + "\\old.txt", "r", encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as readtxt:
    for f in readtxt:
        fname = f.rstrip()
        oldList.append(fname)

# i is index of oldList
i = 0
newList = []
with open(path + "\\rename.txt", "r", encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as readtxt:
    for f in readtxt:
        newName = f.rstrip()
        os.rename(path + "\\" + oldList[i], path + "\\" + newName)
        i += 1
```